# C# static constructor initialization thread safety while filling ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, plinq, static-constructor

I'm calling `var person = PersonDB.pDict["395096"];`

Can anyone explain me why this code blocks:

```
static class PersonDB
{
    internal static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Person> pDict;

    static PersonDB()
    {
        pDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Person>();
        var headers = File.ReadLines(FindPath.DataSetPerson).First().Split(';');


        File.ReadLines(FindPath.DataSetPerson).AsParallel().Skip(1).Select(s => s.Split(';')).ForAll(fa =>
           pDict.TryAdd(fa[0], new Person() { all = Enumerable.Range(0, fa.Length).ToDictionary(t => headers[t], d => fa[d]) })
        );
    }
}

sealed class Person
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> all;
}
```

While this part does not block:

```
static class PersonDB
{
    internal static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Person> pDict;

    static PersonDB()
    {
        pDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Person>();
        var headers = File.ReadLines(FindPath.DataSetPerson).First().Split(';');


        //File.ReadLines(FindPath.DataSetPerson).AsParallel().Skip(1).Select(s => s.Split(';')).ForAll(fa =>
        //   pDict.TryAdd(fa[0], new Person() { all = Enumerable.Range(0, fa.Length).ToDictionary(t => headers[t], d => fa[d]) })
        //);

        Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(FindPath.DataSetPerson).Skip(1).Select(s => s.Split(';')), line =>
        {
            pDict.TryAdd(line[0], new Person() { all = Enumerable.Range(0, line.Length).ToDictionary(t => headers[t], d => line[d]) });
        });

    }
}

sealed class Person
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> all;
}
```

To be honest I'm not even sure if the latter is thread safe now, but at least it runs without problems. I would like to know how to make the PersonDB a thread safe class in such a way that there will be no race conditions or deadlocks. The pDict needs to be created once on usage of the pDict. I thought the static constructor was a nice solution for this but the execution stop on the PLINQ query makes me very unsure...

Comment: The Skip(1) might skip any row because your query is not ordered.

Comment: All of this is probably moot because the CD is much slower than a normal dictionary. Just use a normal dictionary and it will be faster. *Maybe* the CSV line parsing can benefit from parallelism, but at high overhead cost.

Comment: Skip(1) is there to just skip the title of the csv file, filling a normal dictionary with parallel foreach causes the parallel threads to write to the dictionary at the same time, which causes errors so concurrentdictionary is necessary here (but correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not an expert on this)

Comment: I understand why the skip is there but it could skip any row because the query is unordered and parallel.; Yes, the CD is needed with parallelism but writing to a CD in parallel is slow. This is slower than non-parallel writing to a Dictionary. Probably, this is faster without any parallelism.

Comment: I tried to put the Skip(1) before .AsParallel() to check whether it makes any difference but unfortunately it still seems to hang... Could you perhaps give me some advice on how to get this working without taking into consideration whether it is slower in a single threaded manner. I'm just very curious what the problem is in this multi threaded scenario since I need to use it in other parts of my code as well where it in fact is giving me better performance.

Comment: @BigChief But the point is that *here* parallelizing your code is making it *slower*.  The fact that you can parallelize entirely different blocks of code and have it be beneficial is irrelivant to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a static constructor deadlock. The parallel threads access `PersonDB` which blocks until `PersonDB` is statically initialized. Move the initialization code to a different function. Make it return the dictionary instead of modifying `pDict` in place.

I try to avoid static constructors that do things that can fail. Your code certainly can fail because it is IO. If it does the class is permanently hosed. `Lazy` can be better.

Comment: Thanks usr, how to implement Lazy here..?? I could better just make another function GetDictionary(string id) where it returns the Dictionary to make this work..??

Comment: Well, yes, that was my first suggestion. That would work.